# How make users unable to add network printer via IP address?

Tags: windows-7, networking, printing, printer, network-printer

-Windows domain environment:
-Windows 7-10 machines.

My network printers are connected to my print server. Print server then shares out printer with appropriate permissions. I want users to only connect to printers via print server.

How do I prevent a user from directly adding printer via IP address? Thank you.

Comment: "How do I prevent a user from directly adding printer via IP address?" Chnage the group policy that allows them to add/remove devices

Comment: Some printers support a "host access list". Only jobs from PCs whose IP address is in that list can print. If your printers support it (what are the models?), put only the servers' addresses in the list.

Answer (score 0):

In *Administrative Tools* go to *Active Directory Users and Computers* and then group policy. In here you can configure the right policy, such as *Allow Printers to be published*, *Printer Browsing* and *Pre-populate printer search location text*. For more information on controlling printers through group policy you can refer to the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/234270/how-to-use-group-policy-settings-to-control-printers-in-active-directo).